# How to fix MongoServerSelectionError: Server selection timed out after 30000 ms?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am using my nodejs/express js app deployed on AWS lambda since more than 2 years without problem. Recently, I've decided to switch from regular mongodb cluster to mongodb serverless cluster. I updated npm mongoose and mongodb and then app started to no longer working as usual.

I still can make database operation but the connection quickly timeout after the app starts and then the whole app crash.

```
MongoServerSelectionError: Server selection timed out after 30000 ms
    at Timeout._onTimeout (/user/node_modules/mongodb/lib/sdam/topology.js:312:38)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:559:17)
    at processTimers (node:internal/timers:502:7) {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'Unknown',
    servers: Map(1) {
      'undefined:27017' => ServerDescription {
        _hostAddress: HostAddress { isIPv6: false, host: 'undefined', port: 27017 },
        address: 'undefined:27017',
        type: 'Unknown',
        hosts: [],
        passives: [],
        arbiters: [],
        tags: {},
        minWireVersion: 0,
        maxWireVersion: 0,
        roundTripTime: -1,
        lastUpdateTime: 204235345,
        lastWriteDate: 0
      }
    },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: undefined
  }
}
```

I don't know why the host is `undefined` has I provided my atlas cluster uri.

```
const uri = 'mongodb+srv://xxxxxxxx@serverlessinstance.mongodb.net/mydb?retryWrites=true&w=majority' 

module.exports.connectToDatabase = async function connectToDatabase() {
  
  if (conn == null) {

    conn = mongoose.connect(uri, {
      serverSelectionTimeoutMS: 5000,
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true
    }).then(() => mongoose);
    
  
    await conn;
    

  return conn;
};
```

Any suggestion ?

Comment: Try increasing the timeout 

Comment: Just tried this. With no success

Comment: Could you try logging the error from the .catch() method

Comment: No error from the catch method, only the one mentioned above.

Comment: And if you using await  mogoose.connect(), then there no need for the .then()

Comment: Yes I removed the then statement after adding await.

Comment: Quick question do you have another instance of Mongod like `connect-mongodb-session`  And Can You check the line in which your `conn` is called

Comment: OMG Thanks. I just figured out my app was using `AgendaJS` which apparently was causing the timeout error. I don't know why and you made me realize that maybe I should disable and try again to connect. And it works now ! thanks

Comment: Am happy it’s work out well cause your code looked clean  Happy coding

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247203/discussion-between-ogoh-cyril-and-john).